# Angular - Why does my Component get default value from Observable in Service, although it has been changed before?

Tags: angular, typescript, service, behaviorsubject

I've set up an Angular-Service that gets an URL-Parameter and saves it into a BehaviorSubject variable.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ResultService {
  private resultDefault = new BehaviorSubject<string>("0");
  currentResult = this.resultDefault.asObservable();

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe(val => {
      if (val instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
          console.log("resultDefault was:", this.resultDefault.getValue());
          this.resultDefault.next(val.state.root.firstChild.params.id);
          console.log("resultDefault is:", this.resultDefault.getValue());
      }
    });
  }
```

Now I want to access this variable from a Component by subscribing to the Observable.

```
constructor( private resultService: ResultService ) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.resultService.currentResult.subscribe(data => {
    console.log("Component gets:", data);
    this.resultID = data;
  });
}
```

However, what I get is the default value ("0"), although the variable has been changed in the constructor of the Service.

This is what the console outputs, in the following order:

```
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
resultDefault was: 0
resultDefault is: 3
Component gets: 0
```

Am I just overlooking something? Or is this the wrong approach? Looking forward to your answers!

EDIT: I added some console logs. Unfortunately, non of the answers were able to solve my problem yet. I hope someone can still help me.

Comment: are you sure that `this.resultDefault.next(val.state.roote.firstChild.params.id);` was called? and if so was it called before the Component's subscription or after?

Comment: just to make sure  `val.state.roote.firstChild.params.id`   ?  is it a typo ?  i think it should have been `val.state.route.firstChild.params.id`

Comment: `this.resultDefault.next(val.state.route.firstChild.params.id);` also make sure you have the id here , please `console.log()` and check the same most probably the value is not changing

Comment: also try using `this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(routeParams => { console.log(routeParams.id;) });` instead of `this.router.events.subscribe(val => {});` if the value is not changing

Comment: Sorry, ```roote```is just a typo. I console logged all the values before and after they were changed. The console looks like this:
```resultDefault was: 0
resultDefault is now: 3
currentResult is now: 3
Component gets: 0
```